# Boost: iterating over an image region

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, iterator, boost-iterators

I have images that I don't own, with adjacent monochrome pixels, which I currently iterate with dumb pointer-increment.

I now have the need to iterate over 2D regions, so I'm thinking about the best way to provide iterators that are efficient and easy to write.

I need only forward_iterator. If I have a 10x10 image and if I want to iterate on 4x3 upper left region it will iterate on these elements:

```
0 1 2 3 10 11 12 13 20 21 22 23
```

I have two options:

- write it by hand with `boost::iterator_facade`
- use `boost::range_iterator`, which gives me an iterator over the array, and modify its behavior with `boost::iterator_adaptor`

What do you think is the best one?

Comment: I've not used the latter mechanism but `iterator_facade` is dead simple to use...

Comment: It would be convenient to the user if the user can choose which coordinate to increment. Thus, `++iter.x` and `++iter.y` would increment `x` and `y` coordinates respectively, `++iter` would move the iterator in a way that it will eventually sweep the entire 2D area, and `*iter` would dereference the iterator and yield the pixel. I don't have concrete idea how to implement it though.

Comment: @rwong good idea but I really don't need to specify if I iterate by-row or by-column. I just need by-row as it is more cache-efficient

Comment: What do you mean by you "don't own" these images?

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg: I mean that I'm not responsible for allocating the memory of the images, external library provides me the pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two concepts: (i) subimage, and (ii) 1-d iterator over image.

I would start by taking a look at [`vil_image_view` in the VXL library](http://public.kitware.com/vxl/doc/release/books/core/book_7.html).

This separates the concept of image data, from the representation (view) of the data.  The view provides `istep`, `jstep` amd `planestep` increments, and pixel indexing.  Different `vil_image_views` can be created to represent cropped images, from the same underlying data.  This library is only partially compatible with STL, and a good STL implementation would be interesting, but I am not sure of a clean way to implement a 2d iterator in STL.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I didn't look in VXL for a long time, will check it